# GF(113) arithmetic using tables?

Tags: finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I need to work with the Galois Field of (prime) characteristic 113.

I am wondering if it is possible to implement multiplication and division using log/antilog tables (like I already do in different instances of GF(2^k)). I have come up with the following lookup and reverse lookup tables of powers, working with the primitive element 3.

```
Exp[113]=
{
  1,   3,   9,  27,  81,  17,  51,  40,   7,  21,  63,  76,   2,   6,  18,  54,
 49,  34, 102,  80,  14,  42,  13,  39,   4,  12,  36, 108,  98,  68,  91,  47,
 28,  84,  26,  78,   8,  24,  72, 103,  83,  23,  69,  94,  56,  55,  52,  43,
 16,  48,  31,  93,  53,  46,  25,  75, 112, 110, 104,  86,  32,  96,  62,  73,
106,  92,  50,  37, 111, 107,  95,  59,  64,  79,  11,  33,  99,  71, 100,  74,
109, 101,  77,   5,  15,  45,  22,  66,  85,  29,  87,  35, 105,  89,  41,  10,
 30,  90,  44,  19,  57,  58,  61,  70,  97,  65,  82,  20,  60,  67,  88,  38,
  1 }

Log[113]=
{
  -,   0,  12,   1,  24,  83,  13,   8,  36,   2,  95,  74,  25,  22,  20,  84,
 48,   5,  14,  99, 107,   9,  86,  41,  37,  54,  34,   3,  32,  89,  96,  50,
 60,  75,  17,  91,  26,  67, 111,  23,   7,  94,  21,  47,  98,  85,  53,  31,
 49,  16,  66,   6,  46,  52,  15,  45,  44, 100, 101,  71, 108, 102,  62,  10,
 72, 105,  87, 109,  29,  42, 103,  77,  38,  63,  79,  55,  11,  82,  35,  73,
 19,   4, 106,  40,  33,  88,  59,  90, 110,  93,  97,  30,  65,  51,  43,  70,
 61, 104,  28,  76,  78,  81,  18,  39,  58,  92,  64,  69,  27,  80,  57,  68,
 56 }
```

In somes cases, like `24 * 32 = Exp(Log(24) + Log(32)) = Exp(37 + 60) = 90`, it works.
In others, like `104 * 92 = Exp(58 + 65) = Exp(10) = 63` (instead of `76`), it fails.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you want to work with the field $GF(113)$ os an arbitrary finite field of characteristic $113$?

Comment: GF(113) (even though I don't really understand the nuance).

Comment: In that case, it is simply isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/113\mathbb{Z}$, so all the arithmetic can be done very easily.

Comment: I can do it using the modulo operator. My question is whether it is doable with log/antilog tables.

Comment: Your error is in the $exp(58 + 65) = exp(10)$. You can reduce exponents mod $112$ not mod $113$.

Comment: I guess this is the very point that I am missing. Why 112 and not 113 ? Is it because the primitive element is a 112-th root of unity ?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the reason.

Comment: The nuance, Yves, is that there are (infinitely many, non-isomorphic) finite fields of characteristic 113, one for every power of 113.

Comment: Understood. I think I should have said *size* instead of characteristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is in the $\operatorname{Exp}(58 + 65) = \operatorname{Exp}(10)$ since this corresponds to reducing an exponent mod $113$. But since we are working with a $112$'th root of unity, what we can do is reduce the exponent mod $112$, which gives precisely what it should.